# Needing PHP to show multiple rows, but it is only showing me the last row

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The output from the code below only shows me the last row of my data. Any ideas? I want it to show me all rows.

Here is the code:

```
$FinalSet = array();
while ($ResultSet = mysqli_fetch_array($Query)){

 $FinalSet = array(
'idExam' => $ResultSet[0],
'SubjectName' => $ResultSet[1],
'ExamTime' => $ResultSet[2],
 'ExamDate' => $ResultSet[3],
 'IntakeCode' => $ResultSet[4],
'Scope' => $ResultSet[5],
);
 }

 echo json_encode($FinalSet);
```

Comment: Try `$FinalSet[] = array(`

Answer (score 2):

You have to add them to your array. At the moment you are replacing the array itself.

You can do this by using

```
$FinalSet[] = array(
```

instead of

```
$FinalSet = array(
```

You can also use array_push, which does the same:

```
array_push($FinalSet, array(......));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already initialized $FinalSet = array(); and you are storing data single index so your data has been override and you found last row your data. Now you can use $FinalSet[] instead of $FinalSet. You will get all data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You can use `$FinalSet[]` or [array_push()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to push the array content into the main array. Currently, you are jut replacing the same array respective of the loop counts. So you getting the last array value in the variable.

```
$FinalSet[] = array(
     'idExam' => $ResultSet[0],
     'SubjectName' => $ResultSet[1],
     'ExamTime' => $ResultSet[2],
     'ExamDate' => $ResultSet[3],
     'IntakeCode' => $ResultSet[4],
     'Scope' => $ResultSet[5]
 );
```

instead of

```
$FinalSet = array(
     'idExam' => $ResultSet[0],
     'SubjectName' => $ResultSet[1],
     'ExamTime' => $ResultSet[2],
     'ExamDate' => $ResultSet[3],
     'IntakeCode' => $ResultSet[4],
     'Scope' => $ResultSet[5],
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in the loop:

```
while (...) {  
   $FinalSet[] = array(...);
}
```

Comment: Please get in the habit of explaining what the problem is and why your solution works. It makes for better answers.

Comment: @Sverri, thanks. I am new to Stack I'll try my best to provide accurate solution